# Typescript throwing errors for spread operators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm using typescript in react and following file is throwing a lot of errors, I'm not sure why (its working as js), but I suspect something here is to do with spread operators?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Subscribe } from 'unstated'

const getStoreAsProps = (storeArr) => {
  const storeProps = {}
  storeArr.map((value) => (storeProps[value.name] = value))
  return storeProps
}

const withStore = (...args) => (Element) => () => (
  <Subscribe to={[...args]}>{(...args) => <Element {...getStoreAsProps(args)} />}</Subscribe>
)

export default withStore
```

Errors thrown by `tsc` are

> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:14 - error TS1005: '>' expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                   ~~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:16 - error TS1005: ')' expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                     ~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:19 - error TS1109: Expression
>   expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                        ~~~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:26 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                               ~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:30 - error TS1136: Property assignment
>   expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                                   ~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:40 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                                             ~~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:52 - error TS1005: '>' expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                                                         ~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:80 - error TS1109: Expression
>   expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                                                                                     ~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:81 - error TS1109: Expression
>   expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                                                                                      ~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:83 - error TS1110: Type expected.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>                                                                                        ~
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:11:84 - error TS1161: Unterminated
>   regular expression literal.
>
> 11   {(...args) => }
>
> workspace/app/store/index.ts:12:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or
>   statement expected.
>
> 12 )    ~

If it helps, syntax highlighting is breaking there as well

[image]

Comment: Try `import * as React from "react";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors imply that JSX syntax wasn't recognized by the compiler. In order for it to be recognized, the file should have .tsx extension, while it currently has .ts extension.

[`jsx` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) should also be enabled and set to `react`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue:
`let temp: any = ...props.data.map((row:any) => {return row.json});`

React is already imported like above:

```
import * as React from "react";
```

Also tsx option is set to react in tsconfig

And now I answer my own problem:

Ofc if you are working on an object you need to use Object.assign()

```
let temp: any =  Object.assign({}, props.data.map((row:any) => {return row.json}));
```